# UIWindow iPhoneX custom bounds

Tags: ios, uiwindow, uiapplication

I have an old project that doesn't uses autolayout and lot of legacy code. I want to make it compatible with iPhone X till I complete a code rewrite of the entire project. I thought of using NotchKit but it doesn't gives expected results. Is there a way to define UIApplication window's custom frame (which is a subrect of the full screen), and then every ViewController respect that bounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can find padding of iPhoneX

In swift

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let topPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.top
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    let leftPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.left
    let rightPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.right
 }
```

In Objective C

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    UIWindow *window = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
    CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
    CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
    CGFloat leftPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.left;
    CGFloat rightPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.right;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use paddings in each and every UIView I create? That's not the objective I had.

Comment: see this https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Comment: Doesn't serves my purpose. All I want is not to replace reach and every call like subview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height) to subview.frame = CGRectMake(leftPadding, topPadding, width, height).

Answer (score 0):

In Storyboard file, you must check at Use Safe AreaLayout Guides

[image]